# I read the Quran syllable by syllable but I don't know where a word begins and where it ends.If I knew that I could translate them from the dictionary

Tags: grammar, arabic, word-order, words, word-formation

Salaam aleikum. I have learned the entire Arabic alphabet. And also the harakat and long vowels. But I have a big problem. I read the Quran syllable by syllable but I don't know where a word begins and where it ends. If I knew that I could translate them from the dictionary and read them much better. If you could help me on this issue it would probably cause a dramatic jump in quality in my Quran reading and understanding?

Comment: Arabic has spaces between words just like English. What's the problem? The definite article _al_ and some prepositions like _b_ or _l_ are written as prefixes, but don't you think you've got to know at least some basic grammar of a language to be able to read and understand it?

Comment: You could read it in a language that you understand.

Comment: The properly formatted Arabic abjad is cursive and has four different letter forms: initial, medial, final and isolate. The initial and final forms at least are distinct in all letters, and indicate the beginning and end of most words. There are, of course, exceptions (six letters cannot connect to the following letter, creating false word boundaries), but the vast majority of apparent word boundaries are true word boundaries. This, combined with the spaces, should be enough to determine where the words are. Is your copy of the Quran properly formatted?

Answer (score 5):

Here is [Quran word for word](http://corpus.quran.com/wordbyword.jsp?chapter=1&verse=1) – every word is written separately, translated, explained grammatically, and recited  audio by a professional reciter. If you click a word, you are redirected to a more detailed explanation of the word.